# Return the values inside parenthesis in python

Tags: python, regex, parentheses

I'm trying to extract the values of following line inside the parenthesis.

```
    line=(panel, wxID_EXIT, wxT("Quit"),wxPoint(20, 20))
```

expected answer is:

```
    panel, wxID_EXIT, wxT("Quit"),wxPoint(20, 20)
```

but using the following

```
    pattern=re.compile(r'\((.*?)\)')
    match = re.search(pattern, line)
```

I only receive the following output.

```
    (panel, wxID_EXIT, wxT("Quit")
```

Unfortunately my knowledge of regular expressions is very limited.Can someone help me to get the expected answer.

Comment: Well you explicitly request to go only to the first `)`. Why did you add `?` if you don't really want it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with that `.*?`, you turned off the *greedy* aspect of regular expression. Just remove the question mark to enable it again (this is default):

```
pattern=re.compile(r'\((.*)\)')
```

full test:

```
import re
line='(panel, wxID_EXIT, wxT("Quit"),wxPoint(20, 20))'
pattern=re.compile(r'\((.*)\)')
match = re.search(pattern, line)
print(match.group(1)=='panel, wxID_EXIT, wxT("Quit"),wxPoint(20, 20)')

True
```

Comment: check my edit. This regex gives exactly the result you asked for.

Comment: Yeah... Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you can avoid RegEx here:

```
text = '''line=(panel, wxID_EXIT, wxT("Quit"),wxPoint(20, 20))'''
parts = text.split("=")
result = parts[1][1:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
>>> line='(panel, wxID_EXIT, wxT("Quit"),wxPoint(20, 20))'
>>> re.search(r'^\s*\((.*)\)\s*$', line).group(1)
'panel, wxID_EXIT, wxT("Quit"),wxPoint(20, 20)'
```

Or, in straight Python, you can do:

```
>>> line.strip()[1:-1]
'panel, wxID_EXIT, wxT("Quit"),wxPoint(20, 20)'
```

Which first strips whitespace with `.strip()` then trims one character on either side of the string with `[1:-1]`